# Dúvida routerLink e route.navigate(<rota que eu quero>)?

Tags: angular, angular-routes, angular-6

Por que quando eu uso o `routerLink` a página de destino executa os comandos dentro do `ngOnInit()` e quando utilizo o `this.route.navigate([<rota de acesso>])` não é executado?

Gostaria de saber se tem como o `this.route.navigate()` ao ser executado exigir que a página de destino execute os comandos dentro do `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: você esta usando this.route.navigate(['/rota'])?

Comment: ficou confusa sua pergunta. Onde você está executando o `routerLink`? é no mesmo template do component que possui o `ngOnInit`? Onde está executando o `this.router.navigate`? Dentro do `ngOnInit`?  Perguntas relativas ao ciclo de vida é bom dar uma olhadinha nessa página: [Angular Life Cycle Guide](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: Vou tentar simplificar... Tenho uma página que possui o método http GET no ngOnInit. Tenho outras duas páginas que, de alguma forma, irá me redirecionar para a primeira página. Uma delas utilizará a diretiva routerLink e a outro o this.route.navigate.
As funções dentro do ngOnInit da página inicial são executadas quando eu acesso a página através do routerLink, mas não pelo this.route.navigate

Comment: não intendo nunca tive esse problema posta ae um codigo que deu errado

Comment: Na verdade quando você direciona com o `this.router.navigate()` ou `routerLink=[]` é executado o `ngOnInit` do componente. Dê uma olhadinha nas rotas se estão corretas para o devido componente executar e certifique se a rota que chamou o componente pelo `navigate` é o mesmo quando chamado pelo `routerLink`

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar o Resolve do router? https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve. Poderia colocar a requisição dentro do Resolve da rota, assim antes da rota ser chamada a requisição precisa ter terminado. A não ser que seja requisito ela executar dentro do ngOnInit(), o que eu não vejo sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Na página que você vai receber os parâmetros tanto pelo `routerLink` quanto pelo `navigate` pode fazer uma lógica para ver de onde veio.

Ex:

Usando o `routerLink` você passa o parâmetro dessa forma:

```
idPagina1 = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

Usando o `navigate` você recebe dentro do `ngOnInit` dessa forma:

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
        (queryParams: any) => {
        this.idPagina2 = queryParams['id'];
 });
}
```

Portanto, você pode usar uma variável global em que se o parâmetro vier da página 1 o idPagina1 estará diferente de `null`, ou se vier da pagina 2 o idPagina2 estará diferente de `null`. Então, você pode conferir o parâmetro dessa forma:

```
id: number;

ngOnInit(){
if(this.idPagina1 != null){
    id = this.idPagina1;
}else{
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
            (queryParams: any) => {
            this.idPagina2 = queryParams['id'];
            id = this.idPagina2;
     });
    }
 }
```

Não sei se você está usando parâmetros, mas acredito que esteja tentando vir com diferentes parâmetros de diferentes para para acessar uma página em comum. É isso? Caso seja acho que isso te ajuda.

Comment: Na verdade não seria como implementar os parâmetros de rota a pergunta dele